# Update_attributes - Not Sure What It's Saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails API, I have the following line for updating a Model.  As you can see, it accepts a lot of parameters.  But, I have a few questions about this that the current documentation doesn't answer...

```
@updated_special_deal.update_attributes(:category => params[:category], :title => params[:title], :excerpt => params[:excerpt], :description => params[:description], :original_price => params[:original_price], :deal_price => params[:deal_price], :provider => params[:provider], :product_link => params[:product_link], :conditions => params[:conditions], :phone_number => params[:phone_number], :street => params[:street], :city => params[:city], :postal_code => params[:postal_code], :state => params[:state], :country => params[:country], :expires => params[:expires], :image_file_name => params[:image_file_name], :image_content_type => params[:image_content_type], :image_file_size => params[:image_file_size], :image_updated_at => params[:image_updated_at], :public => true)
```

On trying this PUT request via external Client App.  I get this response below...

```
Started PUT "/api/v1/1/special_deals/47?title=The+greatest+deal+ever" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-12 14:39:15 -0700
Processing by Api::V1::SpecialDealsController#update as JSON
Parameters: {"title"=>"The greatest deal ever", "servant_id"=>"1", "id"=>"47"}

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - Validation failed: Provider can't be blank, Description can't be blank:
```

Sure, I wrote those rules in the Model.  But, I'm not trying passing in the Provider attribute or the Description attribute.  So, what's happening here?

- With my .update_attributes syntax above, what happens to the params that aren't included in the PUT request, do they just try to update the Model with blank values?
- And if that is the case, Do I have to submit values for all of a Model's attributes when using update_attributes?

**EDIT**  Rephrasing the question:  How do I write update_attributes so that it only updates the attributes included in the PUT request?

Comment: You are passing both provider and description to `update_attributes`...

Comment: Logan:  How am I passing both provider and description to update_attributes?  I don't see it in my PUT request?  Is it because I have included those parameters in the update_attrbutes?  If so, how can I just write this so that it only updates the params passed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass params to be updated inside of a root element with your model name. So your params should be something like:

```
{"servant_id"=>"1", "id"=>"47", "special_deal":{"title"=>"The greatest deal ever"}}
```

In your controller action, you can load the model and relationships, and then update the model from the "special_deal" params.

```
def update
  servant = Servant.find(params[:servant_id])
  @special_deal = SpecialDeal.find(params[:id])
  @special_deal.servant = servant
  @special_deal.update_attributes(params[:special_deal])
end
```

`update_attributes` simply takes a hash and updates the attributes in the hash. If you have your params be as I mentioned, then `params[:special_deal]` will be equivalent to `{"title" => "The greatest deal ever"}`. Passing that hash into the update attributes call will update only the `title` attribute on your model.

Comment: Logan, to be clear, if I put the params in a root element, update_attribute will update only those params?  Also, is this a good design for a REST API?

Comment: See my edit. `update_attributes` is a very simple method. And yes, 99% of the tutorials you will see online use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Removing:

```
:provider => params[:provider] and :description => params[:description]
```

or make sure they are provided with actual values.

Your model has validations which require either valid values or none (depending on the exact validations used).